# Setting up subdomains on nginx?

Tags: configuration, nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to set a subdomain on nginx.  My setup is a Pylons app running on port 8080 and using proxy from nginx.

The reason why I'm trying to get subdomains to work is to eventually set up dev and staging servers.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include     mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;
    access_log  logs/rentfox.access.log;
    error_log   logs/rentfox.error.log;
    gzip        on;
    sendfile    on;
    tcp_nopush  on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout   75 20;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xxx.net;

        location / {            
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect default;
            root /var/apps/xxx/xxx/public/;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  dev.xxx.net;

        location / {            
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect default;
            root /var/apps/xxx/xxx/public/;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see the xxx.net & www.xxx.net domains but I get a sever not found when I try the dev.rentfox.net domain - do you have the DNS records set up with a wildcard or with the dev sub-domain?

If the DNS is set up properly what do the access and error logs from nginx look like when you access the dev sub-domain do they have any entries in them?