# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Nginx

Tags: nginx, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04, web-hosting, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my particular domain to Tomcat where multipe Application is running, but I'm getting `"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"` ERROR in the browser

My configuration has below

```
server {
        listen   80;

        server_name www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:7070/AppName;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        client_max_body_size 200m;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I configured my Odoo app to forward all requests via Nginx.
You need to add something like this to your Nginx config:

```
upstream tomcat {

    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
        listen   80;

        server_name www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
        proxy_pass  http://tomcat;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        client_max_body_size 200m;
        }
}
```

If this doesn't work, for reference, you may want to check this article: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-odoo-on-a-debian-8-vps-with-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy/

I hope you'll find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to set the proxy_redirect directive in the same way as the proxy_pass directive. see for example [configure-nginx-with-proxy-pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847771/configure-nginx-with-proxy-pass).

```
location ~ ^/stash {
    proxy_pass http://IP:7990;
    proxy_redirect   http://IP:7990/  /stash;
}
```

but I got the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error with this configuration... so i changed it for "proxy_redirect off;" as suggested here, and it solved my problem!

here is the configuration for my gitlab server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name reverseproxy.mydomain.org;

    location /gitlab/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host-Real-IP    $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass       http://172.xx.xx.xxx:10080;
            #proxy_redirect http://172.xx.xx.xxx:10080/ /gitlab/;           
            proxy_redirect   off;           
    }
}
```

NB: i also needed to remove the directive "proxy_set_header Host $host;" for my gitlab server, powered by [docker-gitlab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab).