# Spring Boot and Nginx integration

Tags: nginx, docker, spring-boot, reverse-proxy, proxypass

In my project, web app is developed using Spring boot with default tomcat server.
I am using NGINX as load-balancer and have configured my spring-boot-web-app in NGINX configuration as follows:

```
location /spring-boot-web-app {
     proxy_pass http://spring-boot-web-app/
}

http {
    upstream /spring-boot-web-app {
        server <IP_of_spring_boot_app>:<Port_of_spring_boot_app>
    }
}
```

Now lets say NGINX IP and port as **nginx_ip** and **nginx_port** respectively.
Also working URL for my web app as: **http://web_app_ip:web_app_port/rest/echo/hi**

The above URL works fine. But when i try to hit same URI via NGINX it throws 404. URL used via NGINX as: 
http://nginx_ip:nginx_port/spring-boot-web-app/rest/echo/hi

Is there something i am missing?

Comment: Did you check for the nginx logs?

Comment: Yes. Even i see app log that it intercepting the URL.

Comment: Somehow i feel its more of CORS related problem. Do i need to set any header value?

Comment: You may need to setup proxy_pass_reverse https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847771/configure-nginx-with-proxy-pass

Comment: is $remote_add and $host should be IP of my web-app?

Comment: Keep the variables as is. Nginx resolves them

Comment: did not work for me.. i also tried with replacing with correct IP. One thing- I have vagrant provisioned VM where my web app and nginx are running as docker container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111160/discussion-between-gangaraju-and-sam).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me. Can you try this?

1. Running tomcat

   ```
   docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name=tomcat tomcat:8
   ```
2. Running nginx

   ```
   docker run -d -p 80:80 --link tomcat:tomcat --name=nginx nginx
   ```
3. Go inside nginx container and update the conf

   ```
   docker exec -it nginx bash
   ```

   **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:**

   ```
   server {
      listen 80 default_server;
     server_name subdomain.domain.com;
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080;
         proxy_set_header Host      $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     }
   }
   ```
4. Restart nginx service

   ```
   nginx -s reload
   ```
5. Access the tomcat through nginx from host browser. You may need to add entry to /etc/hosts

   ```
   http://subdomain.domain.com
   ```

Complete nginx conf: [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/chgangaraju/9c74f73494a8dac54ecea93e5e4d55b5)

Comment: Really appreciate your help "Gangaraju". But the docker command you proposed i cant use. Because i am using consul to do it and define dependency.

Comment: It may not fit into your environment. But try to debug your issue, by comparing with these steps and check what you are missing. I would suggest you to run these containers in other environment to cross verify the nginx  configuration/ for better understanding

Comment: Thank you very much Gangaraju for your prompt help..Really appreciate!1

Comment: Accepted the answer as it gave some route to debug. Will post the solution once i get it.