# Friendly URL between docker containers/images

Tags: docker, server, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm creating some projects with docker, but they will be in different images/containers

It's possible to access different docker containers with the same url, like a "friendly url"?

**Example:**

- The main container is in teste.com
- If I access teste.com/project2, teste.com/project3, I want it to go to a different running container in the same server machine.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a webserver(`apache`/`nginx`) to distribute the traffic to different containers.

In your case start a nginx container which will redirect the request to

- container1 - which runs your project1
- container2 - which runs your project2 etc,,

Now in nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name subdomain.domain.com;
  location /project1 {
     proxy_pass http://tomcat1:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host      $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
  location /project2 {
     proxy_pass http://tomcat2:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host      $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

See the following example on: [Configuring Nginx docker container to proxypass to tomcat docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058838/1986826)