# How to fix my authentication and redirection problem?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, redirect, spring-security

I am trying to build a Spring application for a school project and I am facing a few problems configuring Spring Security.

In fact, I have configured Spring Security so that I have two types of users : Employee and "Commercant" (Merchant in French). When I try to log in using the nav bar of my browser, everything goes fine: I can go to the default login page of Spring Security, log in, have access only to the `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` requests I am supposed to use, and I can logout.

However, things get complicated when I try to use a custom login page (which is closer to real life cases). I have a JS page with a button, which sends a `POST` request to the `loginProcessingURL` with valid credentials. I know that the authentication is validated because the network tab of the inspector shows I am redirected to `/valide`, the `defaultSuccessUrl`.

[image]

But as you can see, I can't reach `/valide` because I am instantly redirected to `/login`, just as if my user was not really identified, and my API wanted me to log in to access `/valide`. The 302 code validates that hypothesis because it shows I am immediately redirected when I try to acceed to `/valide`. Do you have any ideas of where it could come from?

Security config:

```java
package com.openclassrooms.api.configuration;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import com.openclassrooms.api.service.CommercantService;
import com.openclassrooms.api.service.EmployeeService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    private CommercantService commercantService;
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/login/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/perform_login/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/erreur")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .userDetailsService(employeeService)
            .userDetailsService(commercantService)
            .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().sameOrigin())
            .formLogin()
                // .loginPage("/index.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/valide")
                .failureUrl("/erreur")
                .and()
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/sessionExpired"))
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder (){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

`CommercantService`:

```java
package com.openclassrooms.api.service;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.openclassrooms.api.models.Commercant;
import com.openclassrooms.api.repository.CommercantRepository;

@Service
public class CommercantService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    CommercantRepository commercantRepository;

    public Optional<Commercant> getCommercantById(final Long id) {
        return commercantRepository.findById(id);         
    }

    public Optional<Commercant> getCommercantByMail(final String mail) {
        return commercantRepository.findCommercantByMail(mail);         
    }

    public Commercant saveCommercant(Commercant commercant) {
        Commercant savedCommercant = commercantRepository.save(commercant);
        return savedCommercant;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mail) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
        Optional<Commercant> com = commercantRepository.findCommercantByMail(mail);
        if (com.isEmpty()){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Mail invalide "+mail);
        }else {
            Commercant commercant = com.get();
            UserDetails user = User.withUsername(commercant.getMail()).password(commercant.getPassword()).roles(commercant.getRole()).build();
            return user;
        } 
    }
}
```

`EmployeeService`:

```java
package com.openclassrooms.api.service;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.openclassrooms.api.models.Employee;
import com.openclassrooms.api.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Service
public class EmployeeService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;   //On crée un EmployeeRepository pour se connecter à la BDD

    public Optional<Employee> getEmployeeById(final Long id) {
        //Méthode qui renvoie un employé selon son identifiant
        return employeeRepository.findById(id);         
    }

    public Optional<Employee> getEmployeeByMail(final String mail) {
        //Méthode qui renvoie un employé selon son identifiant
        return employeeRepository.findEmployeeByMail(mail);         
    }

    public Iterable<Employee> getEmployees() {
        //Méthode qui renvoie la liste de tous les employés
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void deleteEmployee(final Long id) {
        //Méthode qui supprime un employé en BDD selon son ID
        employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        //Méthode qui enregistre un nouvel employé en BDD
        Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return savedEmployee; //Renvoie l'employé enregistré avec son identifiant mis à jour selon la base de données
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Employee> emp = employeeRepository.findEmployeeByMail(mail);
        if (emp.isEmpty()){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Mail invalide "+mail);
        }else {
            Employee employee = emp.get();
            UserDetails user = User.withUsername(employee.getMail()).password(employee.getPassword()).roles(employee.getRole()).build();
            return user;
        } 
    }

}
```

`HomeController`:

```java
package com.openclassrooms.api.controller;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.openclassrooms.api.models.Commercant;
import com.openclassrooms.api.models.Employee;
import com.openclassrooms.api.service.CommercantService;
import com.openclassrooms.api.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    CommercantService commercantService;
    

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Employee Home(){
        return employeeService.getEmployeeById(3L).get();
    }

    @GetMapping("/valide")
    public Employee valide (){
        System.out.println("Authentication validated !");
        return employeeService.getEmployeeById(2L).get();
    }

    @GetMapping("/sessionExpired")
    public String expire (){
        return "Session Expirée";
    }

    @GetMapping("/erreur")
    public Employee erreur (){
        System.out.println("Authentication error!");
        return employeeService.getEmployeeById(1L).get();
    }


}
```

`CommercantController`:

```java
package com.openclassrooms.api.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.openclassrooms.api.models.Commercant;
import com.openclassrooms.api.service.CommercantService;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/commercant")
@PreAuthorize ("hasRole('ROLE_COMMERCANT')")
public class CommercantController {

@Autowired
CommercantService commercantService;

    @GetMapping
    public Commercant commercant(HttpServletRequest request){
            return commercantService.getCommercantById(1L).get();       
    }  

}
```

`EmployeeController`:

```java
package com.openclassrooms.api.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.openclassrooms.api.models.Employee;
import com.openclassrooms.api.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/employee")
@PreAuthorize ("hasRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE')")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")  //même structure qu'au dessus, sauf qu'on rajoute un identifiant : http://localhost:9000/employee/1 ou /2 ou /3
    public Optional<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
        Optional<Employee> emp = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);

        if (emp.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(emp.get().getFirstName());
            return emp;   //ici on renvoie un seul employé au front-end
        } else {
            System.out.println("ABSENT");
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(@RequestParam("ids") List<Long> ids) {
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< ids.size(); i++){
            list.add(employeeService.getEmployeeById(ids.get(i)).get());
        }
        return list;
    }

    @PostMapping ("/auth")
    public void employeeAuth (@RequestBody String requestBody){
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(requestBody);
        String string1 = json.getString("email");
        String string2 = json.getString("password");

        System.out.println(string1 + " " + string2);
    }
}
```

JavaScript function:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("service-button");
const dataContainer = document.getElementById("service-data");

const url = 'http://localhost:9000/perform_login';
const data = "username=otacos%40mail.com&password=otacos";

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  fetch("http://localhost:9000/perform_login", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
    body: data,
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
});
```

EDIT : here are the logs of Spring Security.

First, the log for a classic authentication + logout done by writing HTTP requests directly in the browser, which works fine :

```
2023-03-05T15:43:09.018+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2023-03-05T15:43:09.026+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-05T15:43:09.027+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /
2023-03-05T15:43:12.441+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-03-05T15:43:17.610+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /perform_login
2023-03-05T15:43:17.796+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user 'otacos@mail.com'
2023-03-05T15:43:17.905+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-03-05T15:43:17.928+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl   : Registering session 68E825E98F1B6C3982E5A413440676CF, for principal org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]
2023-03-05T15:43:17.929+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5b8fc6fd]
2023-03-05T15:43:17.930+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]
2023-03-05T15:43:17.930+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /valide
2023-03-05T15:43:17.935+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /valide
2023-03-05T15:43:17.935+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]]       
2023-03-05T15:43:17.936+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /valide
Authentication validated !
2023-03-05T15:43:22.305+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /logout
2023-03-05T15:43:22.305+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]]       
2023-03-05T15:43:22.306+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Logging out [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]]
2023-03-05T15:43:22.307+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler : Invalidated session 68E825E98F1B6C3982E5A413440676CF
2023-03-05T15:43:22.307+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /
2023-03-05T15:43:22.311+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2023-03-05T15:43:22.311+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-05T15:43:22.312+01:00 DEBUG 11016 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /
```

And the trace for an authentication done using the button shown above :

```
2023-03-05T15:48:53.736+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /perform_login
2023-03-05T15:48:53.964+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user 'otacos@mail.com'
2023-03-05T15:48:54.080+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-03-05T15:48:54.106+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl   : Registering session FD94F1CC9DF62780F8D31E362BC7AB09, for principal org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]
2023-03-05T15:48:54.108+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@ba2827]
2023-03-05T15:48:54.109+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=otacos@mail.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_COMMERCANT]]
2023-03-05T15:48:54.109+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /valide
2023-03-05T15:48:54.113+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /valide
2023-03-05T15:48:54.116+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-05T15:48:54.120+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:9000/valide?continue to session
2023-03-05T15:48:54.120+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/login
2023-03-05T15:48:54.124+01:00 DEBUG 18004 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
```

Comment: I host it on a second tomcat server (port 8080) and call the localhost:9000 URL
I would prefer to host it on the Spring integrated Tomcat but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to host the Custom Login page?

When we run application locally and use front-end which access at browser url (default : port 80).
When UI makes calls to loacalhost on different port as 9000 then usually you experience these kind of errors.

If thats the case you can add an nginx application and define routes in the same.

Such that your browser will think that you are making requests to same application but nginx will be routing it to Spring Application.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

Config for your nginx will look like :

server {

```
location /perform_login {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/perform_login;
}
```

}

and Front end fetch will make just localhost call:

fetch("http://localhost/perform_login" ....

Also check on following links:

[Spring Boot and Nginx integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057772/spring-boot-and-nginx-integration)

https://www.nginx.com/blog/running-spring-boot-applications-zero-trust-environment-nginx-unit/

Comment: My custom login page runs on a Tomcat with port 8080, and my back end API runs on the Tomcat integrated inside SpringBoot with port 9000. 
Do you think hosting both on the same server could be a solution ?

Comment: Have them on same port 8080 if both are in single application.  And let me know if you still see http status 302. 
If both are sitting in different applications then use nginx or other HTTP server for routing.

Comment: I think I don't know how to set-up both applications on the same port without creating a conflict, because of the Spring-integrated Tomcat.

Comment: Since there are two applications then you can use Nginx infront of each app and use the routing accordingly.

Comment: Then I have to say I have not understood how I am supposed to configurate nginx. I tried adding the proxy but it seems not to be acknowledged by the front-end

Comment: When you say you tried using proxy. is it httpd.conf you are updating?
If yes, that should also solve the issue.
What is the error on UI? 
Nginx can be installed by following link- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/
Its one of the ways to solve it.