# installing nodejs and mongodb on nginx web server in ubuntu os

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to install nodejs and mongodb on nginx webserver in ubuntu operating system but i am not getting it. I installed nginx server but couldnt getting how to install nodejs and mongodb on nginx web server. I also installed php mysql and phpmyadmin with nginx server in the ubuntu and all those are running fine. Now i want to install nodejs and mongodb over there but i am not getting it. Is it possible to host php websites and nodejs application using the same nginx web server.?????

Comment: Please help me out with this how to do install so that all the things to work propertly

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use reverse proxy. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847771/configure-nginx-with-proxy-pass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847771/configure-nginx-with-proxy-pass)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to install MEAN stack and LEMP stack in Ubuntu.

I am assuming that your are using Ubuntu 14.0 LTS.

Kindly follow the below tutorial links to setup nodejs with nginx as a reverse proxy method.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Installing Mongodb.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Other task, adding users and config ip in mongodb Google it.