# Configure Nginx with a Subdomain

Tags: configuration, nginx, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I've done my prior research, but cannot seem to find how to properly configure nginx to accept a subdomain.

I currently have it properly configured for mydomain.com, but not analytix.mydomain.com:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name     *.mydomain.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mydomain/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mydomain/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mydomain/homelaunch/;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mydomain/homelaunch/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

the `server_name` declaration is accepting `<anythinghere>.mydomain.com` which is good.

If I access `analytix.mydomain.com` , it throws a Http 500 default which is fine, because its throwing it from the existing application at `mydomain.com`

The domain is already propogated to this server I'm trying to access it on.

How can I designate a folder, at a path, to house the contents for `analytix.mydomain.com` ? I would assume i would require changing an attribute in the nginx conf (as shown above)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx subdomain configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9905378/608639), [Setting up subdomains on nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1174554/608639), etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a new `server` block where you set the `server_name` to the desired domain. The normal directory and file structure of nginx looks as follows:

```
/etc/nginx
|
|---- /sites-available
|     |
|     |---- default.conf
|
|---- /sites-enabled
      |
      |---- default.conf -> ../sites-available/default.conf
```

You have to create a new file in `sites-available` with the new `server` block in it for your sub-domain and create a symbolic link to this new file in `sites-enabled`. A simple reload of nginx will bring your new server up.

Your new file structure looks as follows:

```
/etc/nginx
|
|---- /sites-available
|     |
|     |---- analytix.conf
|     |
|     |---- default.conf
|
|---- /sites-enabled
      |
      |---- analytix.conf -> ../sites-available/analytix.conf
      |
      |---- default.conf -> ../sites-available/default.conf
```

Here are the commands involved to do this very fast directly on your server:

```
# cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
# cat default.conf > analytix.conf
# editor analytix.conf
```

Change the line `server_name *.mydomain.com;` to `server_name analytix.mydomain.com`.

```
# ln -s analytix.conf ../sites-enabled/
# nginx -t
```

Only continue if it says that your configuration is okay (which it should be).

```
# service nginx restart
```

That’s it (please note that all of the above commands are meant for a Debian based distro and some commands might differ if you use something else).

---

In order to deliver the contents of a different software on your server you have to change the `root` directive in your configuration and point it to the document root of the other software.

```
# editor analytix.conf
```

Change `root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mydomain/homelaunch/;` to `root /path/to/other/software;` and reload your nginx.

```
# nginx -t && service nginx reload
```

That’s it, your new application should be serving now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The only issue I had was with ```ln -s analytix.conf ../sites-enabled/``` but when I changed the file to an absolute path it worked as expected - ```ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/analytix.conf ../sites-enabled/```

Comment: You need to be in the correct directory to do as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try change server_name:

```
server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)\.mydomain\.com$";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be quite a few examples online referencing `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and its companion `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` but I cannot find these directories by default in a docker container image I downloaded last year. My guess is that this is a legacy setup (please correct me otherwise).

Anyway, all I needed was two server blocks, one for each domain and subdomain, as shown in the [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/). As far as Nginx is concerned, it doesn't matter whether it's a subdomain or an entirely different domain. Here's a modified version for subdomains:

```
http {
  index index.html;

  server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/example.com/htdocs;
  }

  server {
    server_name sub.example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/sub.example.com/htdocs;
  }
}
```

Of course, test it with `nging -t` to see if it's OK.

Comment: Re `sites-available` & `sites-enabled`: These are usually found in an Apache webserver config, where files in `-enabled` are symlinks to (and thus a subset of) files in `-available`. But since it's not really Apache-specific, some people use it with nginx as well. But for nginx you have to create these folders yourself (easy), and do the symlinking yourself (Apache provides convenience scripts around the latter). I'm running such an nginx setup, and it's served me well. Whether it's legacy or not is a matter of taste. I'm a big fan of symlinks when used in the right place at the right time.